# Re-opening hidden panels in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I unfortunately deleted the menu (QGIS 1.8.0) in print composer (settings for labels, etc).

How do I display it again?

The menu is gone in all my projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click into menu or toolbar and you should get some checkboxes to turn everything visible again.

[image]