# Qgis printing bug

Tags: qgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reopen hidden panels in print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/how-to-reopen-hidden-panels-in-print-composer)

I am new to QGIS and I have a problem with printing, After a bug, I do not have longer access to the functionality of windows, adjust the layout and content.
I reinstalled the software without success, and deleted the preferences files in the computer (they reappear automatically when the software starts) I copied these same files from another computer (without the bug) on my computer, without success either.
Did you have to do with this bug? Thanks

Comment: please provide more details. Which Qgis-Version are you using? Windows? Printing service? Printing works marvelous on my Win XP machine and i believe that your problem is related to your computer or printer configuration. For additional information make a screenshot!