# Adjusting QGIS Print Composer output resolution?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am using QGIS 2.12.

I would like to adjust the Print Composer's output resolution for "Export as Image" and "Export as PDF".

The default is 300 dpi, but I would like 600 or 1200.

Multiple websites say that it *can* be done, but they don't say *how*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This parameter is directly available in QGIS Composer window:

[image]

**EDIT :** If `Composition` tab is not visible, you can easily set it up by right-clicking bellow the tabs bar and selecting `Composition`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my Composer only has two tabs, "Item properties" and "Atlas generation".  How do I add the "Composition" tab?  I can't add a screen shot here, but I hope you understand what I mean.  I only show 2 tabs.

Comment: I just found the following:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/how-to-reopen-hidden-panels-in-print-composer.  It works for me, although "Composition" shows up in a separate pane, rather than a tab as shown in your screenprint.  But it works, my question is answered!

Comment: Just edited my answer to explain how to make `Composition` tab visible!

Answer (score 4):

In the newer version of QGIS (i.e. 3.12) we can right-click elsewhere on the toolbar -> switch on **Layout Panel** and go to **Export Settings** as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before export on top menu, Right Click  -> Composition ->Paper and quality ->Export Resolution
 then set it whatever you like.