# Extracting individual images from gridded map

Tags: qgis, select

I am using QGIS (2.8.6-Wien) and I would like to do the following: Load a GeoTIFF, add a grid-layer (with cell size specified in pixels), select some cells and save each cell content as an individual image (e.g. as a .png file).

Since I am not very experienced with QGIS, I am not sure whether this is actually feasible with QGIS. What I managed to do so far is the griding. Below is a small example, where I used the [Natural Earth Admin 0 - Countries dataset](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_projections.html). I did the griding with "Vector" -> "Research Tools" -> "Vector Grid", Parameters X: 4.0, Y: 4.0 (output grid as polygons).

[image]

Now, I would like to select the cell indicated by "X" (Panama) and save the cell content as an image. I tried some of the QGIS geoalgorithms (Vector selection tools) but failed to reach my goal. Ultimately, I would like to select several cells and save each cell as an image, individually.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Did you try select by location?

Comment: You could use an the atlas generator in print composer. Add a field to the grid layer and use that field to filter the atlas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution using Atlas Generator

**Step 1: Add a field to the vector grid layer to use as a filter**

Field name: `Filter`; field type: whole number; field length: 1; expression: 0.
[image]

**Step 2: Selected cells in grid layer and change `Filter` value to 1**

- Select all cells that you want saved as images
- Open the grid layer attribute table, turn on editing for this layer, and enter 1 in the `Filter` field for the selected features

[image]

**Step 3: Set a Print Composer layout**

- Create a new print composer: Project menu > New Print Composer
- Set page size proportional to the dimensions of the grid cells. Eg, if the cells are square, make the page length the same as the page width.

[image]

- Add a map, and re-size it to fill the page

**Step 4: Generate an Atlas, using the grid layer as the coverage layer and Filter field as filter**

- Set up the atlas:
  [image]
- Select the map item, and under item properties check the box for "Controlled by Atlas."
- Set "Margin around feature" to 0

[image]

**Step 5: Preview and Export Atlas**

1. On the atlas toolbar, click the Preview Atlas button.
2. Use the left and right arrow buttons to flip through the pages of the atlas and make sure they are the pages you want to print.
3. Click the button "Export atlas as images."

[image]

4. At this point you have the option to set the image width/height in pixels, or specify image resolution in DPI.

[image]

Note: The option to specify export resolution after clicking the Export button was introduced sometime after version 2.8. [In earlier versions of QGIS, export resolution can be specified in the Composition panel of the Print Composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170344/adjusting-qgis-print-composer-output-resolution).

Comment: That's already quite close to what I would like to do, thanks! I would like to save the cells exactly as they are, i.e. 300 by 300 pixels for instance. If I see correctly, the suggestion so far requires to set the image size manually which distorts the actual pixel-resolution. Is there a way how to save the patches directly?

Comment: It's possible to specify the dpi or size in pixels of the export image. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Another way to approach this question would be to use Python code to print directly from the QGIS project. I'm not very experienced with Python so I can't help with that method, but here's a link that would help if you want to explore that possibility. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html#output-to-a-raster-image

Comment: Step 5.4 (choosing export options) was not available in my version of QGIS (2.8.6-Wien). After "Export atlas as images", the patches were directly saved, hence my question. With another version it works exactly as asked. Thank you very much, csk!

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link to method for specifying export resolution in earlier versions.