# How to change layout DPI in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, dpi, layout-manager

I am trying to change the DPI of QGIS3 (3.6) in the layout manager. 
However, as the Figure below shows (lower left corner), the DPI (300 by default) seems to be read only.

[image]

I tried to click the textbox. But it's not allowing input.
There is no spinner control QGIS 2 either as said about the the older QGIS2 in GIS.SE:

[Adjusting QGIS Print Composer output resolution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170344)

How can change the DPI from the QGIS 3 GUI?

Comment: There seems to be an "Export resolution" box a little bit higher, in "Export settings". Changing the value does not change the value of the layer_dpi variable but perhaps it still works.

Comment: It's refreshed if you close and reopen the layout window. It's not refreshed automatically when changing with the spinbox button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go a little bit more up, in the "export settings" tab, instead of the "variable" tab:

[image]

Variables are indeed read-only.