# Adjusting QGIS 3.6 Print Composer default output resolution?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

When exporting a print layout to image or PDF in QGIS 3.6, the default resolution is 300dpi. I'd like to change that default.

There's an analogue question here: [Adjusting QGIS Print Composer output resolution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170344/adjusting-qgis-print-composer-output-resolution)

But that targets QGIS 2.12 and the answer does not apply to QGIS 3.6.

There is a *variable* for DPI which is set to 300 but I'm unable to change it:
[image]

Comment: The answer for that question applies to QGIS 3.6 as well.

Comment: No the answer for that question doesn't apply here as Marco noted. Therefore, this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole printer composer changed from QGIS 2 and not everything is as smooth as someone would like. It is a shame that the page layout is so hidden, for instance, it took me a while to figure it out how to access it in QGIS 3.

The `Export Settings` now is in the `Layout` tab as shown below.

[image]