# Set DPI in QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis-3, atlas

How can I set DPI (or reduce quality in some other way) in QGIS 3.12 when exporting Atlas as PDF? My output is 300 MB for 89 A4 pages and the quality/resolution is unnecessarily high.

I can't find the composition tab as mentioned in [Adjusting QGIS Print Composer output resolution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170344/adjusting-qgis-print-composer-output-resolution) (qgis 2).
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under `Layout` tab, there is an `export settings` in which you can adjust the `export resolution`. It is a global setting that works for atlas and an individual layout exports.

[image]