# Reducing file size of QGIS PDF export?

Tags: qgis, export, pdf

I've created a layout printed to PDF (A4, 1:1000) which shows an area of OS mapping (vector data) and this prints to over 8MB - is there a way to reduce the output size of the pdf?

I've tried removing all the unnecessary layers and this helps but only slightly.

Comment: Please provide details on number of layers, number of features and export settings.

Comment: 8mb seem a lot for A4 vector PDF, are you sure you did export as vector and not raster ? did you include the attributes ? did you try to check the "Simplify geometries to reduce output file size" (in the advanced option) ?

Comment: Thanks both - I've got 'always export as vectors' and 'simplify geometries' both ticked on the export window (and nothing else), and compression to 'lossy'.  It's 12 layers but all OS mapping so 00's-000's of features (road labels, buildings etc)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Comments are intended to be ephemeral -- Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: Have you tried [reducing the dpi?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356666/set-dpi-in-qgis-atlas)

Comment: @BERA did reducing the dpi should have an effect for vector export ? (in ArcMap increasing the dpi get better PDF export with minimal size increase so dpi and vector export interact but how...)

Comment: Oh I didnt read everything, OP is exporting vectors. I only create PDF:s with rasters and reducing dpi is making those alot smaller. So I don tknow

Comment: You might add to your information what QGIS version you are using.  Is this a geospatial pdf export?  You might show a portion of your map; sometimes symbology and labels can add considerable complexity.  On the other hand, sometimes something simple can be the problem.  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44656  So you could run some test exports with different layers turned off to see if one is a problem.